# Ошибка при addListener

Tags: javascript, extjs

Добрый день! Использую ExtJS 2.0.
Столкнулся с проблемой добавления слушателя в компонент:

```
my.component.ResultGrid = function {
  var ResultGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    listeners: {
      'rowdblclick': function(grid, rowIndex, event) {
        loadRecord(rowIndex);
       }
    }
  });

  my.component.ResultGrid.superclass.constructor.call(this, {
    items: [ResultGrid]
  });   

 function loadRecord(rowIndex) {
  alert(rowIndex);
 } 
};
Ext.extend(my.component.ResultGrid, Ext.Panel);
```

из этого компонента

```
my.MyPanel.Register = function() {
  var ResultGrid = new my.component.ResultGrid();

  ResultGrid.items.items[0].addListener({
    rowclick: function(grid, rowIndex, event) {
      loadRecord(rowIndex);
    }
  });

  my.MyPanel.Register.superclass.constructor.call(this, {
    items: [ResultGrid]
});
};
Ext.extend(my.MyPanel.Register, Ext.Panel);
```

При выполнении появляется ошибка:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: loadRecord is not defined
```

Как я понимаю ошибка в неправильном значении scope? Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Comment: _Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так_ - объявляешь _loadRecord_ как **локальную функцию**. Поэтому в функции `my.MyPanel.Register = function() {` она уже не будет видна

Comment: а возможно добавить   Listener   без изменения     my.component.ResultGrid ?

Comment: не понял вопрос. у тебя проблема в добавлении слушателя, а в том, что ты пытаешься вызвать функцию _loadRecord_ когда она у тебя не определена

Comment: Вся проблема в том что бы добавить слушателя из my.MyPanel.Register в ResultGrid, вызывающего функцию, уже определенную в my.component.ResultGrid. Иначе придется половину функционала из my.component.ResultGrid в my.MyPanel.Register перенести. Просто большого опыта JS не имею и возможно все усложняю.

Comment: Да, ты усложняешь на столько, что я не понимаю что ты хочешь сделать. У тебя уже добавляется обработчик в _my.component.ResultGrid = function {_ а потом ты еще раз добавляешь обработчик, уже в панели. зачем?

Comment: 'rowdblclick' и 'rowclick' разные обработчики. Грубо говоря my.component.ResultGrid базовый компонент, используемый в различных модулях, и изменять нежелательно. А my.MyPanel.Register дополнительный модуль, в котором требуется my.component.ResultGrid с дополнительным слушателем.

Comment: Не вижу проблемы. Ты вполне себе добавляешь оба разработчика. Я повторюсь: проблема в том, что ты хочешь использовать функцию _loadRecord_ - хотя ты ее не объявил.